# How to check incoming String is of which type in java?

Tags: java, string

I want to check for the incoming string is of which type.

Something like this:

```
public void checkType(String str)
{
    if(str is Integer){
        //do Integer stuff
    }
    if(str is Float){
        //do Float stuff
    }
    if(str is Boolean){
        //do Boolean stuff
    }
    if(str is Double){
        //do Double stuff
    }
}
```

What is the better way to do this?

Comment: There is a logical problem here, because a given input "number" might be castable to `Integer`, `Float`, or `Double`.  In this case, which one do you choose?  It would be better to have the caller use a specific overloaded method for a specific type.

Comment: Nothing object-oriented about this.

Comment: The better way to do this is to realize your question doesn't make as much sense as you think

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm reached to the solution. For Integer and Float I used the Java Regular expression.

Like this:

1. For Integer :

   ```
   String intRegex = "[0-9]+";
   if (inputString.matches(intRegex)) {
       //do Integer stuff
   }
   ```
2. For Float :

   ```
   String floatRegex = "^([+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)$"; 
   if (inputString.matches(floatRegex)) {
       //do Float stuff
   }
   ```

I think this is also Good way to identify String is of Integer or Float type...?

For Boolean stuff I didn't find the good solution yet. so I'm just used equals operator for that.

Thank you...

Answer (score -1):

For what you are trying to do you are better off to declare your method argument as an Object type rather than a String, for example:

```
public void checkType(Object var) { 
    // ..... Your code .....
}
```

The only thing is that you will need to know what object type was supplied for your specific method code. You can do this quite simply with a single line of code, for example:

```
public void checkType(Object var) { 
    String varType = var.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();

    // ..... Your code .....
}
```

The declared String variable named varType will hold the name of the Object supplied. Now you can use your if/then's or the switch() method to determine what was actually supplied, for example:

```
public void checkType(Object var) { 
    String varType = var.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase();

    switch (varType) {
        case "STRING":
            // do String stuff
            break;
        case "INTEGER":
            // do int stuff
            break;
        case "FLOAT":
            // do float stuff
            break;
        case "DOUBLE":
            // do double stuff
            break;
        case "BOOLEAN";
            // do boolean stuff
            break;
        case "JLABEL":
            // do JLabel stuff 
            // (any object can be supplied)
            break;
    }
}
```

That should do it I would think (error trapping is up to you).

Comment: OP wants to check what "type" the String contains and not an arbitrary object like in your answer.

Comment: @Tom - I was basing my answer on the OP's final sentence within his post: "What is the better way to do this?"

Comment: @DevilsHnd - I'm using SAX Parser for reading xml file and for that purpose i'm overrided **startElement** and **endElement** methods. This method argument's is bydefault String so what can I do for that?

Comment: @DevilsHnd So you completely change the premise of OPs situation and think that will work out of the box?